# Pageable pagesize greater than 2000? throw exception

Tags: spring, pagination

I would like to know is there a way to throw an exception if user requests the pagesize > Pageable pagesize limit (2000).

Currently, if I request 3000 records, it quietly returns 2000 records. I want to throw an exception in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? I'm also come up with same requirement

Comment: I think I added a check against user input. I am throwing bad request if the request limit exceeds the supported pagesize.

Comment: How did you do that ? Will you show some code ?

Comment: In Controller method gave page defaults as this ->
`@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10) Pageable page`

I used some config to read the max pageSize and rejected the request with 400 Bad request.